# Como inflar uma view customizada dentro de um view no recyclerview?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

Seguindo este [exemplo](https://github.com/RohitSurwase/AndroidDesignPatterns/tree/master/dynamic-recycler-view),estou criando um recyclerview expansível,para criar uma sessão de comentários e respostas de comentários no meu app.Nele e possível criar um linear layout vertical,em que serão inflados vários textviews.Porém preciso fazer um layout mais complexo,um outro linear layout contendo uma imagem e um textview:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <com.makeramen.roundedimageview.RoundedImageView
        android:id="@+id/roundedImageView"
        android:layout_width="24dp"
        android:layout_height="24dp"
        android:layout_margin="4dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        app:riv_corner_radius="5dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        tools:text="This is a textview" />
</LinearLayout>
```

No viewholder os textview estão sendo inflados desta maneira,como no exemplo:

```
for (int indexView = 0; indexView < intMaxNoOfChild; indexView++) {
    TextView textView = new TextView(context);
    textView.setId(indexView);
    textView.setPadding(0, 20, 0, 20);
    textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    textView.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.background_sub_module_text));
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    linearLayout_childItems.addView(textView, layoutParams);
}
```

De que maneira posso inflar essa view customizada e para cada view inflada,atribuir um texto e uma imagem?

Comment: Olha só não entendi esse For. Acho que você deve pesquisa mais

Answer (score -1):

De uma olhada nesse link acho que vai ajudar. 
https://medium.com/@harivigneshjayapalan/android-recyclerview-implementing-single-item-click-and-long-press-part-ii-b43ef8cb6ad8